# String comparison for equality

Tags: java, string, methods, equals

I  have  this  code,

```
class  Test{

public static void main(String args[])
{
Boolean a;
Boolean b;
char [] c={'S','t','r','i','n','g'};

a=("String".replace('g','G')=="String".replace('g', 'G')); 
b=("String".replace('g','g')=="String".replace('g', 'g'));

System.out.println("---"+a);
System.out.println("---"+b);
System.out.println(c.toString()=="String");
}
```

The  Out  put  is 
---false
---true
false

I  did  visit  JLS  documentation  by  oracle where it says. 
The replace method:
Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.
If the character oldChar does not occur in the character sequence represented by this String object, then a reference to this String object is returned. Otherwise, a new String object is created that represents a character sequence identical to the character sequence represented by this String object, except that every occurrence of oldChar is replaced by an occurrence of newChar.

when the O/p one is false why the O/p second  is true?

JLS document says about toString method:
This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
then  why  not  O/p  third  is  true?

Can  any  one  please  explain  it  to  me

Thanks  in  advance
GPAR

Comment: Use equals insted of ==

Comment: I'm guessing this is because of the string pool used internally, where identical strings won't be created twice. On a side note: format your code.

Comment: @Uhla no, this is not that this question is about. `ToYonos` no, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: It's related to [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), but the answer to that question doesn't address the other part of what's going on here: the `String.replace()` method doesn't create a new string instance when there's nothing to actually replace (thus allowing the reference-equality check to succeed). So not a duplicate per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=("String".replace('g','G')=="String".replace('g', 'G'));
```

This returns `false`, because the `replace` method returns a completely new `String` instance. The check `==` returns `false`, because both parts refer to different `String` instances.

```
b=("String".replace('g','g')=="String".replace('g', 'g'));
```

This returns `true`, because the `replace` method returns the `String` instance on which it was called, if `oldChar` and `newChar` are the same ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28char%2Cchar%29)). Since `"String"` is an interned String, both parts are referring to the same instance.

```
c.toString()=="String";
```

This returns `false` again, because `toString()` returns a new `String` instance containing the array representation. This representation can look like this `[C@50206be6`. That means even a `c.toString().equals("String")` call wouldn't return `true`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, that is right, thank you. I've tested it with `System.out.println(c);`, but this is not the same as `System.out.println(c.toString());`.

Comment: Now you've got a complete answer. +1

Comment: Then  cant  we  have  String  from  array  of  character?  Sorry  this  is  diverting  from  my  original  question.  i.e  char[] c  in  my  code  to  String?

Comment: JLS  documentation  says  replace  method  returns  old  String  reference  only  when  there  is  no  char  available  for  replace.  i.e  only  if  'g'  in  my  example  was  not  available.  Here  its  not  the  case.  In  all  other  case  it  will  create  a  new  String.  Am  I  missing  something? @Tom

Comment: @Gpar You can create a String out of a char array by using `new String(c)`. As you can see in the linked source code, the `replace` method does "nothing" if `oldChar` and `newChar` are the same.

Comment: Thanks  @tom  my  last  2  points  are  clear  but  is  String.replace('g','G')  on  left  hand  side  of  assignment  operator  is  different  from  one  on  the  right  hand  side?  is  it  not  one  object  in  a  string  pool?

Comment: Again  I  am  diverting  my  question  a  bit  here  What  will  toString  is  for?  if  it  does  not  even  return  a  String?  @tom

Comment: @Gpar No, they are not in the string pool, because they are created with `new String(...)`. To add them to the pool, call `intern()` on a string obejct: `"String".replace('g', 'G').intern() == "String".replace('g', 'G').intern()` is `true`.

Comment: @Gpar `toString` returns a `String` and it usefull to get a string representation of an object. The standard implementation of it (in the class `Object`) creates somethin "cryptic" like this: `[C@50206be6`. `[` means that the object is an array type and `C` means that is of type `char`. `@50206be6` is a memory adress. You can override the `toString` method in your own classes to change that behavior.

Comment: Sorry  again,  I  got  my  answer  to  the  previously  asked  question  @tom.  But,  Howcome  "String"=="String"  are  equal  and  created  in  the  string  pool  and  not  String.replace('g','G')?  Can  you  please  explain  this  to  me?

Comment: @Gpar `#replace` creates a new String instance using the `new` operator. That means, calling that method twice creates the String instances `A` and `B` which contain the exact same value. That means `A == B` is `false` (due to the different instances), but `A.equals(B)` is `true` (due to the same value). `"String"` retrieves the interned String reference. If you call `"String"` x times, you will always get the exact same String instance, instead of new ones. Calling `A.intern()` will add `A` to the String pool. So `"StrinG"` will give the exact same reference as `A` holds.

Answer (score 5):

`"String".replace('g','g')` makes no changes and returns the original string. Both the string literals are in the string pool as a single object. So

```
 "String".replace('g','g')=="String"
```

That's why your `b` boolean was true.

As for `c`, you are calling `toString()` on a `char` array. A `char` array is not a `String`.. There is no reason that should return the same instance as another `String` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the == operator checks if the object is actually the same. 
If you want to compare the content of the object, you should use .equals()

It might be a bit confusing why the first check return false but not the second. 
I think it might be due to .replace(a, b) where a == b does not actually modify the string and 
so the instance is the same, whereas when the strings are altered the instance is different.

So in short: Use a.equals(b); instead of a == b;

Comment: Thanks  I  do  know  the  difference  between  the  equals  method  and ==  operator.  I  just  want  to  figure  out  which  method  of  String  creates  new  string  and  which  one  returns  the  same  reference?